# jQuery plugin call internal function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, anonymous-function

I want to call removeSomething() (see in line 9) internally:

JS-Code is:

```
    (function($){
      $.fn.extend({
        Engine: function(options) {
          var defaults = {
           ...
          };
          var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

          removeSomething();

          //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
          //Public Functions ------------------------------------------------------
          //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

          this.removeSomething = function() {
            ...
          }; 
        }
      });
   })(jQuery);
```

But if I call removeSomething console outputs that removeSomething is not a function, how do I have to call this function? The function should be available internally and externally.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When declaring it with `var` or other `= function() {...` syntax, the function needs to be defined *before* you use it, and called however it was defined, in this case:

```
this.removeSomething = function() {
  ...
}; 
//*then*
this.removeSomething();
```